# strange problems with C++ exceptions with mingw

Tags: c++, exception, mingw32

I have encountered a strange problems with exceptions using mingw and managed to cut it down to the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void test(int a) {
    if (a < 0) {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("a < 0");
    }
}
void test_file(std::string const & fName)
{
    std::ifstream inF(fName.c_str(), std::fstream::in);
    if (!inF) {
        cout << "file error -> throwing exception" << endl;
        throw ios_base::failure("could not open input file '" + fName + "'");
    }
}

int main()
{
    try { test(-5); }
    catch(std::exception& e) {
        cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << " .. continue anyway" <<endl;
    }

    try { test_file("file-that-does-not-exist"); }
    catch(std::exception& e) {
        cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The first exception is caught, but the second one does not, so I get the nice Windows error-box informing me that my application has stopped working :-(
The full command-line output is:

> Exception caught: a < 0 .. continue anyway
>   file error -> throwing exception
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

The same happen also with other exceptions (like std::runtime_error).

Am I doing something wrong, or is the problem somewhere else?

System info: Windows 7 x64, latest mingw32 (re-installed yesterday using mingw-get from mingw.org).

Thanks a lot in advance.
Michal

Comment: More details: I found that my IDE (Code::Blocks) uses linker option "-static-libgcc". When I remove it, it works as expected. This really looks like a bug to me.. Any reason to (not) use this option, in general?

Comment: **Update**: The code works if compiled as `g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ main.cpp` or simply `g++ main.cpp`. The only version that does not work is `g++ -static-libgcc main.cpp`---which is set up in my IDE ;-)  Is it a bug?  And, more importantly, are there any reason for choosing on of the first two over the other one?

Comment: @ Michal: plausible bug. It would be a bug in Code::Blocks then (failure to deduce c++ specific compiler flags)

Comment: @ sehe: what you are saying is that `-static-libgcc` is not supposed to work without `-static-libstdc++` for C++ code? I did not know that (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, on XP SP3 with MingW:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.4.0/configure --prefix=/mingw --build=mingw32 --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --disable-werror --enable-threads --disable-symvers --enable-cxx-flags='-fno-function-sections -fno-data-sections' --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-sjlj-exceptions --with-pkgversion='TDM-1 mingw32' --with-bugurl=http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/bugs.php
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.4.0 (TDM-1 mingw32)
```

Results in a.exe:

```
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ntdll.dll (0x7c900000)
    kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/kernel32.dll (0x7c800000)
    msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/msvcrt.dll (0x77c10000)
```

Output

```
Exception caught: a < 0 .. continue anyway
file error -> throwing exception
Exception caught: could not open input file 'file-that-does-not-exist'
```

So this is soft evidence pointing in the direction of

- library incompatibility
- environmental differences
- bug (?) in your version of MingW

Comment: What version of TDM - SJLJ or DW2 exception unwinding? As far as I know, the 'official' mingw uses DW2 (since gcc 4.4), while TDM offers both and recommends SJLJ as the default choice..

Comment: SJLJ (as shown in the answer `--enable-sjlj-exceptions` but also verified with `objdump.exe a.exe -s -x| egrep -i 'tdm|sjlj|dwarf|dw2'`)

Comment: Just out of interest - could you try to compile it with `-static-libgcc`? (See my comment above for reasons why.)

Comment: Just did, no problem for me. HOWEVER: when using **cygwin g++** with `-static-libgcc` it _does_ crash (it runs ok without the flag) (but you'd get a whole differen output to `ldd`.) Are you mixing up compiler installations?

Comment: I have only one compiler installed, gcc that comes with mingw (no cygwin) - so no, I am not mixing compilers. However, I have found a possible cause of the bug, see my update of the original post above.

Comment: Ha. thanks for the update. Feel free to [asnwer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4263/discussion-between-sehe-and-michal-kaut)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you're doing anything wrong there, this is pretty standard and works quite well under Linux.

I would suggest [raising a query](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mingw-users) with the MinGW people. Even if it's *not* a bug, they should be able to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having a problem with this (6 years later), except mine is found with MSYS2, cmake/ninja/mingw32 on windows 7:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(FailedExceptions )
add_executable(FailedExceptions  main.cpp foo.c)
```

Output:

```
$ cmake .. -GNinja
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/cc.exe -- works
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/msys64/home/sferguson/src/vis/build

$ ninja -v
[1/3] C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cc.exe    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/FailedExceptions.dir/PortDescription.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\FailedExceptions.dir\PortDescription.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/FailedExceptions.dir/PortDescription.c.obj   -c ../PortDescription.c
[2/3] C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\c++.exe     -MD -MT CMakeFiles/FailedExceptions.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\FailedExceptions.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/FailedExceptions.dir/main.cpp.obj -c ../main.cpp
[3/3] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\c++.exe    CMakeFiles/FailedExceptions.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/FailedExceptions.dir/PortDescription.c.obj  -o FailedExceptions.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lgcc_eh -lgcc_eh -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

$ ./FailedExceptions.exe
Exception caught: a < 0: iostream error
file error -> throwing exception

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The only catch is that I also need to link some (any) c file, even if I don't use anything it provides.  In this case I did it with `foo.c`:

```
int foo() { return 0; }
```