# Mixing C and C++ causing exceptions to terminate

Tags: c++, c, cmake, mingw

I am porting a project from MSVC to mingw.  The project contains C and C++.  However, whenever an exception is thrown, instead of being caught, std::terminate gets called and the application crashes.  I can't understand why so any advice would be appreciated.

My toolchain is cmake/ninja/mingw32 in a MSYS2 environment installed in Windows.

## MCVE:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(FailedExceptions)
add_executable(FailedExceptions c_funcs.c main.cpp)
```

---

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main() {
    try  {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        std::printf("reading file\n");
        boost::property_tree::read_xml("nonexistant-file", pt);
        std::printf("provider file read\n");
    } catch (...) {
        std::printf("Exception caught\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// c_funcs.c
int SomeCFunction()
{
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
$ cmake .. -GNinja
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/cc.exe -- works
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/msys64/home/sferguson/src/vis/build

$ ninja -v
[1/3] C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cc.exe  -MD -MT c_funcs.c.obj -MF c_funcs.c.obj.d -o c_funcs.c.obj   -c ../c_funcs.c
[2/3] C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\c++.exe -MD -MT main.cpp.obj -MF main.cpp.obj.d -o main.cpp.obj -c ../main.cpp
[3/3] C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\c++.exe  c_funcs.c.obj main.cpp.obj  -o FailedExceptions.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lgcc_eh -lgcc_eh -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32

$ ./FailedExceptions.exe
reading file

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
$
```

## Trace:

I can get this trace from Dr. Mingw.  It really does appear that the crash happens between construction of the exception and the actual throw.

```
ntdll.dll!_NtTerminateProcess@8
ntdll.dll!_RtlExitUserProcess@4
kernel32.dll!_ExitProcessStub@4
msvcrt.dll!___crtExitProcess
msvcrt.dll!__cinit
msvcrt.dll!__exit
msvcrt.dll!_abort
FailedExceptions.exe!uw_init_context_1
FailedExceptions.exe!boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error::xml_parser_error
FailedExceptions.exe!boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >
FailedExceptions.exe!main
FailedExceptions.exe!__tmainCRTStartup  [D:/develop/scripts/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c @ 334]
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8
```

## Troubleshooting:

- I found some posts from 5-10 years ago suggesting that this could be a conflict between mingw's dw2 and sjlj libraries, but I only have the `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` binaries installed which come with the mingw-w64-i686-gcc-libs package in the msys pacman repository.
- I tried changing my CMakeLists.txt file to compile everything with C++ with `project(FailedExceptions LANGUAGES CXX)`.  This prevents cmake from building my C files. So it does work for the MCVE, but my full project is missing all C content.
- I've added `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fexceptions)` but it seems to have no effect.  I've confirmed with `ninja -v` that this flag is added to the C-file compilation command.
- As soon as I remove the C file from the build, everything works. But even though I'm not using the C-file in this MCVE, I still use it in my big project.
- I've found another smaller example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46689104/1723954).  I can reproduce that problem IFF I also compile a C file in that same project.

Comment: Where is `int SomeCFunction()` called?

Comment: is `boost::property_tree::read_xml` not taking a stream as parameter instead of a string?

Comment: @YSC int SomeCFunction() isn't called anywhere.  It's simply linked.  That's one of the strange details here.  I dont NEED to call SomeCFunction() to destroy my exceptions in the main.cpp.  I just need to link to it.

Comment: @tobi303 There is an overload of `read_xml` which accepts a `const string&`, then opens a file with that name.  That is the overload I am invoking.  See [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/xml_parser/read_xml_idp910001728.html)

Comment: @Stewart ah ok didnt see that one. thx

Comment: and what about boost ptree ? is it essential to the MCVE ?

Comment: Since C does not have exceptions, the likely answer is whenever a thrown C++ exception encounters a stack frame from a C function, it explicitly fails, since the exception cannot be properly propagated. This was the case, at least, with early versions of gcc, where an explicit compilation option was needed to compile C code with proper support for C++ exceptions.

Comment: @Massimiliano Janes  I couldn't reproduce it by throwing a primitive, but the boost stuff I chose to show is all header-only so it should be fairly simple.  I haven't figured out a pattern between what crashes and what doesn't.  I'll see if I can find a simpler way to reproduce it.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765599/strange-problems-with-c-exceptions-with-mingw)'s a good example of a very similiar situation (if not identical).    The cause of that problem is a mix of static/dynamic libraries.  That isn't the problem here, but it shows the same symptoms.

Comment: I'm not sure why cmake generates two -lgcc_eh flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [feature(bug?)](https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2017-August/066128.html) in cmake implicit library detection introduced in cmake [3.1](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-December/059234.html). CMake thinks that in C mode GCC needs to link with `gcc_eh`, which breaks C++ exception handling.

You can disable implicit library detection by adding this to CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES "")
```

(Don't know how to exclude just `gcc_eh` from the list)

Comment: It turns out that when I use this command, `gcc_eh` is the only library excluded.  The others are all included with the CXX link and so this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

RustyX's answer is the accepted one, but I also found another number of work-arounds that seem to work:

- `set_source_files_properties(filename.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)`
- `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/cpp/compiler)`
- `set(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS c)`.

But RustyX's is the best answer so far.

Edit:  The last one doesn't work.  It still builds with the C compiler.  I'd also need to remove `c` from `CMAKE_C_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to rustyx answer above (I'm not allowed to comment), this is fixed in cmake 3.10 per this pull-request: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1460

I tested with CMake 3.10.2, and it seems like exceptions now work without having to specify the work-around cmake stanza rustyx is mentioning.